# periodic function parallel with other tasks

Tags: java, multithreading

I have implementing a Groundstation software.It continuously read Serial input at 1Hz for new data and is going to update different part of the software. this is how i am doing it so far:(just important parts)

Refresher function:

```
public void refresher(SerialPort rx){
                   refreshed++;
                    readRX(rx);
                  if(refreshed<5) return;
         parseString(lastTelemetry);

         updateModel(Double.parseDouble(parsedLastTelemetry.get(telemetry.get("heading"))),Double.parseDouble(parsedLastTelemetry.get(telemetry.get("pitch"))),Double.parseDouble(parsedLastTelemetry.get(telemetry.get("roll"))));

}
```

Action event for connect button:

```
connect.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            if(!portSelect(portNum)) return;
            disconnect.setDisable(false);
             Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              try {
                while (true) {
                  refresher(rx);
                  Thread.sleep(1000L);
                }
              } catch (InterruptedException iex) {}
            }
          };
       Thread thr1 = new Thread(r1);
       thr1.start();
```

Serial reader function:ReadRx

```
private void readRX(SerialPort rx){
                    while(ss.hasNextLine()){
                        String temp = ss.nextLine();
                        if (temp.isEmpty()) continue;
                        if(temp.charAt(0)!='7'|| temp.charAt(1)!='0' || temp.charAt(temp.length()-1)!=';') continue;
                        if(temp.lastIndexOf("7098")!=0) continue;

                        lastTelemetry = temp;
                        System.out.println(lastTelemetry);
                        break;
                    }
}
```

The problem is when software is reading from serial CPU fan starts to work like hell and software looks like its not responding. and when i try to close software is is not responding either.
It may be a silly question but i want a way that refresher function runs every 1 sec parallel to other processes and other parts do their own tasks normally.\

Please dont answer me like an expert:) I am new to java and javafx and never have done this job before.

Comment: I found the problem that programe didnt respond.  i removed while(true) in event handler but now the problem is it happends only one time. i get only one telemetry string from serial not every one sec.

Comment: `ss.hasNextLine()` is probably making a blocking call. Is there an `is DataAvailble` method for the class. As far as timing goes you could look at `java.util.Timer`